# Issue with multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I need to do a subquery within a subquery. For example, on a given day (3-July-14) we have 2 services done (see below). Each of these services has three costs, a basic, additional labour and additional parts charge. These three added up become our OverallCharge. We then need to determine the min, max and avg of these overall charges.

I know how find out the OverallCharge and minimum, maximum and average overallcharge required.

```
SELECT MIN(OverallCharge) AS MinOverallCharge, MAX(OverallCharge) AS MaxOverallCharge, AVG(OverallCharge) AS AverageOverallCharge
FROM (SELECT ServiceId, Sum([S.BasicCharges]+[S.AdditionalLabourCharges]+[S.AdditionalPartCharges]) AS OverallCharge 
FROM Service AS S 
GROUP BY ServiceId) ;
```

The next part is finding out the services per service day, which I have done successfully,

```
SELECT Service.ServiceDate, Count (Service.ServiceId) AS NumServices
FROM Service
GROUP BY ServiceDate;
```

I now need to combine the two (somehow) and find out the amount of services done, the minimum and maximum overall charge as well as the average and group by **service date** and not service ID. (I.E. fin on any given day, what the minimum and maximum overall charge of a service was and what was the average overallcharge that day). It should appear in columns of, date, services done, min, max and avg overallcharges. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you show some example data please?

Comment: what do you mean by example data sorry?

Comment: Well you could copy some data from your tables, and the result of the above two queries separately and then make up the result and show this is what I have, this is what I get using the queries, this is what I want.

Comment: Well in out initial table we have three seperate columns of charges, the sum statement as seen above totals these charges. The select statement above sorts these overall charges into min,max and avg values grouped by a service id. I now need to find out how many services have been done on a particular date (the second group of statements) and find out the mon, max and avg overall charges for that day

Comment: The table looks like this
ServiceId ServiceDate BasicCharges AdditionalLabourCharges AdditionalPartCharges
1 4/07/2014 $200.00 $40.00 $55.00
2 4/07/2014 $200.00 $0.00 $0.00
3 3/07/2014 $200.00 $120.00 $90.00
4 3/07/2014 $200.00 $100.00 $75.00
5 3/01/2014 $200.00 $0.00 $0.00

Comment: we need to get this data and make it look like 

ServiceDate NumServices MinOverallCharges MaxOverallCharges AverageOverallCharges
03-Jan-14 1 $200.00 $200.00 $200.00
03-Jul-14 2 $375.00 $410.00 $392.50
04-Jul-14 2 $200.00 $295.00 $247.50

Comment: I should have mentioned this, could you edit your original post and not on the comments? As comments would be more messy to read.

Comment: that any better @PaulFrancis

Comment: Unfortunately not @Nic Charkow

Comment: Excuse me @PaulFrancis is there anyway i can contact you (email) to help me figure this out, and to transfer files (swear on my life not spammy malicious files) to make understanding this issue easier